# PHP-based Auth for sickbeard, sab, maraschino

Tags: php, authentication, nginx

I have a media center which also serves as a low-volume personal nginx server.

Currently, sickbeard, sabnzbd and maraschino are all reached through subdomains, such as sickbeard.domain.com, which are each proxied through nginx to the appropriate port for that service's server. They are each individually secured by their own auth systems, which I don't entirely understand (I tried reading the code, but it's way over my head and in Python, which I know very little about) but they all use the basic auth popup window, which I think is hideous and redundant.

I also have a website, secured by a session-based authorization with a nice form, using php, that I created as part of a tutorial in php (Fort Knox, this ain't.)

What I want is to go to my website, log in to my pretty form, and have links there that take me to all of my services, without having to go through a challenge screen every time. How can I begin to do this? I tend to think my Google-fu is pretty good, but I'm not even sure where to start.

---

Additional notes:

I put the bones of this together years ago now, but if I recall I went with the subdomain scheme because I was having trouble getting nginx's proxy_pass to work with subfolders. I'm not wedded to it, but I do think it looks nice and clean.

Ideally, I would also like to somehow serve the above services through nginx, so I don't have to have so many open ports.

I also wouldn't mind advice on my php auth scheme. I had a hard time finding tutorials between basic auth and complex systems involving a database of users. I am the only user. I keep my credentials in a flat file outside the path of the site, and I have no need to grow beyond that. I just want an attractive integrated login form, instead of a popup straight out of the 90s.

Comment: I've been digging deeper into Sabnzbd and doing a lot of research, and it's based off WSGI. I finally found where it does its auth check, and now I guess I just need to learn Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sab and Sickbeard are WSGI based, and use the CherryPy libraries. I did a lot of research and decided I could create a new auth method that manually pulled from my php session files and used bcrypt for the hash checks. But I realized I'd stand the risk of my changes being overwritten every time I updated.

Maraschino is also WSGI based, but uses the flasks framework. I had the same realizations as above, but while going through the documentation and code for that, I realized that Maraschino is a lot more powerful than I thought, and the only thing I would want to do on either Sab or Sickbeard that I can't do with Maraschino is non-routine system maintenance, like changing ports or api keys.

So my conclusion is that I'm going to close the ports for Sab and Sickbeard to outside calls, do all my routine activities through Maraschino, and focus my development efforts on getting a better login screen for that. I'll still have multiple ugly auth screens, but I'll encounter them much less frequently. The biggest issue I'll have with that is that when I change my password, I'll have to do it in three different locations.